# Isomorphism on integral homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that we have a  two spaces $X,Y$ with finitely generated homology and a map $f: X \to Y$. I have read that if we wish to show that $f$ induces an isomorphism on integral homology it suffices to show that it induces an isomorphism on homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ a prime number. This should follow by some argument using Universal Coefficients Theorem.

This question comes from Quillen's paper on the computation of Higher K-groups for a finite field. I was inspecting the case of $\mathbb{Q}$ where using UCT we can show that in that case that,

$$H_*(X,\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Q} \to H_*(Y,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$$
is an isomorphism but I don't think from this we should get an isomorphism on the free parts of the homology.

Comment: It only tells you that you have finite kernel and cokernel. Similarly an isomorphism on Z_p homology tells you that the kernel and cokernel of your map on integral homology are finite groups of order coprime to p. Combine the finite field statement for all p (you don't even need the statement for Q) to see that the kernel and cokernel are trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was very very elementary. So I think I should post the solution myself. A direct application of UFC shows that the map,
$$H_*(f): H_*(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H_*(Y,\mathbb{Z})$$
becomes an isomorphism after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}_p$ for every prime number. For the case of $\mathbb{Q}$ this shows that the kernel and cokernel have no free part (here I am using that both groups are finitely generated abelian groups). Similarly tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}_p$ shows that in the torsion part the prime $p$ is not appearing. Since this is true for every prime $p$ the torsion part must vanish and $H_*(f)$ is an isomorphism.